# Segmentation of foreground from background

Tags: c++, opencv, image-segmentation

I'm currently working on a project that uses a *Lacatan Banana*, and I would like to know how to further separate the foreground from the background:

[image]

I already got a segmented image of it using erosion, dilation, and thresholding only. The problem is that it is still not properly segmented.

Here is my code:

```
    cv::Mat imggray, imgthresh, fg, bgt, bg;
    cv::cvtColor(src, imggray, CV_BGR2GRAY); //Grayscaling the image from RGB color space
    cv::threshold(imggray, imgthresh, 0, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV | CV_THRESH_OTSU); //Create an inverted binary image from the grayscaled image
    cv::erode(imgthresh, fg, cv::Mat(), cv::Point(-1, -1), 1); //erosion of the binary image and setting it as the foreground
    cv::dilate(imgthresh, bgt, cv::Mat(), cv::Point(-1, -1), 4); //dilation of the binary image to reduce the background region
    cv::threshold(bgt, bg, 1, 128, CV_THRESH_BINARY); //we get the background by setting the threshold to 1
    cv::Mat markers = cv::Mat::zeros(src.size(), CV_32SC1); //initializing the markers with a size same as the source image and setting its data type as 32-bit Single channel
    cv::add(fg, bg, markers); //setting the foreground and background as markers                                                                
    cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat::zeros(markers.size(), CV_8UC1);
    markers.convertTo(mask, CV_8UC1);    //converting the 32-bit single channel marker to a 8-bit single channel
    cv::Mat mthresh;
    cv::threshold(mask, mthresh, 0, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY | CV_THRESH_OTSU); //threshold further the mask to reduce the noise
    // cv::erode(mthresh,mthresh,cv::Mat(), cv::Point(-1,-1),2);
    cv::Mat result;
    cv::bitwise_and(src, src, result, mthresh);  //use the mask to subtrack the banana from the background
    for (int x = 0; x < result.rows; x++) { //changing the black background to white
        for (int y = 0; y < result.cols; y++) {
            if (result.at<Vec3b>(x, y) == Vec3b(0, 0, 0)){
                result.at<Vec3b>(x, y)[0] = 255;
                result.at<Vec3b>(x, y)[1] = 255;
                result.at<Vec3b>(x, y)[2] = 255;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my result:

[image]

Comment: here is the result image [link] (http://imgur.com/KG619PS) i am not yet quite familiar as how the segmentation works so please bear with me :)

Comment: also should i be using contours or any other techniques for this?

Comment: This image actually looks like an easy example for taking a threshold. Have you tried a single, simple binary threshold and played with the threshold values before your combination of Otsu filters?

Answer (score 0):

As the background is near gray-color, try using Hue channel and Saturation channel instead of grayscale image.
You can get them easily.

```
cv::Mat hsv;
cv::cvtColor(src, hsv, CV_BGR2HSV);
std::vector<cv::Mat> channels;
cv::split(src, channels);

cv::Mat hue = channels[0];
cv::Mat saturation = channels[1];

// If you want to combine those channels, use this code.
cv::Mat hs = cv::Mat::zeros(src.size(), CV_8U);
for(int r=0; r<src.rows; r++) {
    for(int c=0; c<src.cols; c++) {
        int hp = h.at<uchar>(r,c);
        int sp = s.at<uchar>(r,c);
        hs.at<uchar>(r, c) = static_cast<uchar>((h+s)>>1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can i ask why in hsv? a lot of people i ask also said that it is easier in hsv color space, but they didnt even tell me the reason, sad.

Comment: @HarveyC https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV Take a look at here. In short, Hue means "color direction" and Saturation means "color strength". Banana is mostly yellow-type color so Hue will mostly similar in banana area.

Answer (score 0):

adaptiveThreshold() should work better than just level-cut threshold(), because it does not consider absolute color levels, but rather a change in color in small area around the point being checked.

Try replacing your thresholding with adaptive one.

Answer (score 0):

Use a top-hat instead of just erosion/dilation. It will take care of the background variations at the same time.

Then in your case a simple thresholding should be good enough to have an accurate segmentation. Else, you can couple it with a watershed.

(I will share some images asap).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I tried to apply your advises and was able to come up with this

[image]

However as you can see there are still bits of the background,any ideas how to "clean" these further, i tried thresholding further but it would still have the bits.The Code I came up with is below and i apologize in advance if the variables and coding style is somewhat confusing didn't have the time to properly sort them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2\core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat COLOR_MAX(Scalar(65, 255, 255));
Mat COLOR_MIN(Scalar(15, 45, 45));


int main(int argc, char** argv){

Mat   src,hsv_img,mask,gray_img,initial_thresh;
Mat   second_thresh,add_res,and_thresh,xor_thresh;
Mat   result_thresh,rr_thresh,final_thresh;
// Load source Image
src = imread("sample11.jpg");
imshow("Original Image", src);
cvtColor(src,hsv_img,CV_BGR2HSV);
imshow("HSV Image",hsv_img);

//imwrite("HSV Image.jpg", hsv_img);

inRange(hsv_img,COLOR_MIN,COLOR_MAX, mask);
imshow("Mask Image",mask);

cvtColor(src,gray_img,CV_BGR2GRAY);
adaptiveThreshold(gray_img, initial_thresh, 255,ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV,257,2);
imshow("AdaptiveThresh Image", initial_thresh);

add(mask,initial_thresh,add_res);
erode(add_res, add_res, Mat(), Point(-1, -1), 1);
dilate(add_res, add_res, Mat(), Point(-1, -1), 5);
imshow("Bitwise Res",add_res);

threshold(gray_img,second_thresh,170,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV | CV_THRESH_OTSU);
imshow("TreshImge", second_thresh);

bitwise_and(add_res,second_thresh,and_thresh);
imshow("andthresh",and_thresh);

bitwise_xor(add_res, second_thresh, xor_thresh);
imshow("xorthresh",xor_thresh);

bitwise_or(and_thresh,xor_thresh,result_thresh);
imshow("Result image", result_thresh);

bitwise_and(add_res,result_thresh,final_thresh);
imshow("Final Thresh",final_thresh);
erode(final_thresh, final_thresh, Mat(), Point(-1,-1),5);

bitwise_and(src,src,rr_thresh,final_thresh);
imshow("Segmented Image", rr_thresh);
imwrite("Segmented Image.jpg", rr_thresh);

waitKey(0);
return 1;
}
```